# Install .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows Server Core Docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dockerfile

I am struggling to install .NET Framework 3.5 on docker container. I have 4.5 installed already, but need 3.5 to run one Service. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
SHELL ["powershell"]


RUN Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET ; \  
    Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45

RUN dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /all

COPY Startup Startup
COPY Service Service



RUN "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe" WCS.WindowsService.exe


RUN mkdir Temp\Logs

ENTRYPOINT C:\Startup\setupBatch.bat

COPY ContainerApi ContainerApi

RUN Remove-WebSite -Name 'Default Web Site'  
RUN New-Website -Name 'ContainerApi' -Port 80 \  
    -PhysicalPath 'C:\ContainerApi' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["ping", "-t", "localhost"]
```

When I try to build this, it gives me error on line `RUN dism`

> Error: 0x800f081f
>
> The source files could not be found.
>   Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

Now, even if I run `dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /all` inside the docker (docker exec) it will still give me the same error.

Anyone with any help?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I took the following steps to resolve this issue:

1. Got hold of the Windows Server 2016 Core ISO file. Mounted the file on local computer.
2. Extracted the {mount}:/sources/sxs folder into a zip file (sxs.zip). Ensure that the .NET Framework 3.5 cab file (microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package.cab) is present in the sxs folder. In my case, this was the only file present in the sxs folder.

[image: sxs folder]

3. Copy the sxs.zip file to my container. I copied it using the dockerfile of the image.
4. Unzip the file to C:\sources\sxs folder in the container.
5. Used the Install-WindowsFeature powershell command to install the feature.

   ```
   Install-WindowsFeature -Name NET-Framework-Features -Source C:\sources\sxs -Verbose
   ```

   [image: install command]

Hope this helps. I also found the following blog useful in understanding the on-demand features.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2012/05/14/windows-8-and-net-framework-3-5/

Comment: I know I have to avoid the +1 or thanks comments, but you sir are a life savior

Comment: No luck following these exact instructions it will still fail. This is probably not the correct solution.

Comment: @After_Sunset I just did this - it works. The only caveat is that **one has to enable the Windows Update service** on the docker instance, since it'll likely be disabled by default and `Install-WindowsFeature` requires this to work even when providing sources. You can disable the service afterwards.

Answer (score 13):

For those who are still are in need of .Net3.5 and .Net4.X (4.7.2 for my case) version in one image.

Please note that MSFT is aware of this demand, and have a base image for this scenario.

Use `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:3.5-20191008-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` in your dockerfile.

Saved me all the installation hassles.

Comment: This base image is working well for me. I would rather not have to obtain an ISO image and run an additional command during the image build process, so this is a perfect solution for my needs.

Comment: WARNING: This base image does not have security patches applied, and therefore (beyond being out-of-date security-wise) will not work on hosts that have the February 2020 security patches per: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4542617/you-might-encounter-issues-when-using-windows-server-containers-with-t

Comment: Sadly, this is the only solution, I've tried tons of things, and eventually, I used the image mentioned in the answer to use `dotnet 3.5`. In my case, I'm using WiX Toolset to build the installer of the app, so having a separate Docker (Windows) image for that is okayish.

Comment: Same situation as you @MeirGabay. Wix is after dotnet 3.5 but this code is 4.8. 
Don't think a 3.5 container is going to help me in that case :/