# Specific version of Powershell in a Docker image for testing

Tags: powershell, docker, scripting, powershell-2.0

Anyone know how I can get a build of Windows with Powershell 2.0 running in a Docker container for testing?  I've looked at all the official images from MS and none of them seem to have support for it.  I have a client I'm helping with getting away from their old machines, but I have to write some scripts that will  be run in the old environment (PS 2.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a link to a Windows Server image with Net Framework 3 installed, which has Powershell v2 included.  Using the command from @Niklas above, I now have a working Powershell v2.0 environment for testing!  See below for the docker image link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59525183/5445457

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about specific Docker image, but you can use Powershell 2.0 simply by running  `powershell.exe -version 2` with latest Windows 10 for example.

[Reference.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/windows-powershell-2-0-deprecation/)